# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed - Why can't I start my bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I was trying to create my own discord bot but I can't even go past the get running part.

```
# bot.py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

What have I done wrong? What am i missing? Help..